# How to calculate min(date) in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

1. I am using AWS QuickSight to create some simple reports.
2. Based on the dates column I need to find min of date group by particular
   dimension.
3. I am using option "Add calculated field" for this where I
   am applying "min" function to date column. This particular column is
   already marked as "measure" and it is of type Date
4. The expression looks something like `min("periods")` OR `min({periods})` OR `min(periods)`. None of these works.
5. While creating this calculated field I am getting following error

> At least one of the arguments in this function does not have correct
>   type. Correct the expression and choose Create again.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you cannot take the minimum of a date if the date is stored in as a DATETIME.

extract() the parts of the date you want and concatenate() them back together as a string, then use the toInt() or toDecimal() function to create a data-type compatible with the min() function.

Answer (score 0):

I use to to this extract('YYYY',date) * 365 + extract('MM',date) * 31 + extract('DD',date) and then max on the result

Comment: It doesn't work : Try 31-12-2020 and 01-01-2021. However, extract('YYYY',date) * 10000 + extract('MM',date) * 100 + extract('DD',date) is fine !